# How to calculate hashCode of this class

Tags: java, hashcode

I'm trying to calculate hashcode of one class, but I got stackoverflow. How can I do this correctly? I genered it by IntelliJ idea, but still. Got stackoverflow, I know the reason (probably) but I really want to calculate proper hashcode..

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestA testA = new TestA();
        TestB testB = new TestB();
        testA.id = 1;
        testA.name = "test";
        testA.testB = testB;
        testB.testA = testA;
        testB.id = 1;
        testB.name = "test";



        System.out.println(testA.hashCode());
    }
}

class TestB {
    int id;
    String name;
    TestA testA;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof TestB)) return false;

        TestB testB = (TestB) o;

        if (id != testB.id) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(testB.name) : testB.name != null) return false;
        return testA != null ? testA.equals(testB.testA) : testB.testA == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (testA != null ? testA.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}


class TestA {
    int id;
    String name;
    TestB testB;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof TestA)) return false;

        TestA testA = (TestA) o;

        if (id != testA.id) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(testA.name) : testA.name != null) return false;
        return testB != null ? testB.equals(testA.testB) : testA.testB == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (testB != null ? testB.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I included main function too. You can easily open this..

Comment: don't know whether you notice it, but you've already got a hashcode implementation, so what's the problem

Comment: Try to run this - I got stackoverflow

Comment: that has nothing to do with your hashcode. You have circular dependencies between testA and testB

Comment: @Stultuske I'm not sure how that is supposed to answer the question or help him, unless you are trying to imply that having circular references is always wrong (which it isn't).

Comment: no, they indeed aren't. but the chance of calling hashcode vs calling circular references to cause stackoverflow errors ..

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a way to walk the object tree without entering into an infinite loop. This can be achieved by storing the visited objects in a *thread-local* `Set` and stopping when entering a `hashcode` while `this` is in that set.

And you can't just willy-nilly use a `HashSet` to store the 'visited' objects, because it internally calls your `hashcode` so the problem is just shifted elsewhere and you still get a stack overflow. Luckily there's a container that uses identity instead of equality, however it's the Map variant, not the Set. Ideally you want `IdentityHashSet`, but it doesn't exist, however the still useful `IdentityHashMap` exists. Just use the keys as the actual contents and use dummy values.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestA testA = new TestA();
        TestB testB = new TestB();
        testA.id = 1;
        testA.name = "test";
        testA.testB = testB;
        testB.testA = testA;
        testB.id = 1;
        testB.name = "test";

        System.out.println(testA.hashCode());
    }
}

class TestB {
    int    id;
    String name;
    TestA  testA;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof TestB))
            return false;

        TestB testB = (TestB)o;

        if (id != testB.id)
            return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(testB.name) : testB.name != null)
            return false;
        return testA != null ? testA.equals(testB.testA) : testB.testA == null;
    }

    private static final ThreadLocal<Set<Object>> VISITED = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new HashSet(10));

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        Set<Object> visited = VISITED.get();
        if (visited.contains(this))
            return 0;

        visited.add(this);
        try {
            int result = id;
            result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (testA != null ? testA.hashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        } finally {
            visited.remove(this);
        }
    }
}

class TestA {
    int    id;
    String name;
    TestB  testB;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof TestA))
            return false;

        TestA testA = (TestA)o;

        if (id != testA.id)
            return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(testA.name) : testA.name != null)
            return false;
        return testB != null ? testB.equals(testA.testB) : testA.testB == null;
    }

    private static final ThreadLocal<Map<Object, Object>> VISITED =
            ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new IdentityHashMap<>(10));

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        Map<Object, Object> visited = VISITED.get();
        if (visited.containsKey(this))
            return 0;

        visited.put(this, this);
        try {
            int result = id;
            result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (testB != null ? testB.hashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        } finally {
            visited.remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The two `VISITED` variables can be a single variable, but since your classes don't have a common superclass (other than `Object`) I had to make two of them.

**Caveat:** When the tree contains multiple times the same instance of a class, the hashcode of that instance will be calculated multiple times. This is because everytime that instance is done visiting, it's removed from the list. This is because you don't want hard references to these instances to remain in the thread-local Map, preventing garbage collection.